# native script equivalent to window.localStorage with vuejs app

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

Starting out on a new app of reasonable size, VueJS/typescript is the frontend choice. Currently persisting the data into localstorage with https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist

Before venturing much further into the build, i know this app will also need to be a mobile app, native script + vuejs looks like a nice combo.. but my question.

What is the best way to replicate localStorage in a mobile app with native script?

About 5 years i built my last mobile app for ios, I used titanium with SQLite. SQLite was ok, not blazing fast but it was good enough for what i needed. Is SQLite still the way to go for mobile apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [nativescript-localstorage](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-localstorage/) plugin which mimics `localStorage` on Browser by saving the key pairs to a JSON file.

There is also [nativescript-sqlite](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-sqlite) if you prefer to go with SQLite.